# C++ Vectors: Why is this piece of code not working?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
vector< vector< vector<int> > > myArray(5, vector< vector<int> >(4));
vector<int> testArray();
myArray[0][0].push_back(testArray);
```

I don't understand. I'm just trying to append a new element to it.

Edit: Second line was wrong but this still doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector< vector< vector<int> > > myArray(5, vector< vector<int> >(4));
    vector<int> testArray;
    myArray[0][0].push_back(testArray);
    return 0;
}
```

The compile error:

pnt.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pnt.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector >::push_back(std::vector >&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:733: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator]

Comment: I don't know of a better way to do it. I'm porting some Python code because it was inefficient. This is the fastest way I could think of that still seemed somewhat clean.

Comment: what error are you seeing?  Is it a compile error or a runtime problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vector<int> testArray();
```

Should be:

```
vector<int> testArray;
```

`vector<int> testArray();` is a forward declaration of a function called `testArray` which returns `vector<int>`.

You also have one level of indirection too much:

```
myArray[0].push_back(testArray);
```

or

```
myArray[0][0] = testArray;
```

Comment: @cBMtb Then you need to update your question with an exact error message. Erik’s answer fixes *one* error in your code. It’s hard to see whether there are more.

Comment: Wait, I have a matrix with a vector for each element. Why should I do myArray[0] instead of myArray[0][0] when I want to place the element in the [0][0] vector?

Comment: @cBMtb, at the `[0][0]` level, you want to insert `int`s, not another vector.

Answer (score 1):

myArray is a vector of vector of vector of int. myArray[0] is a vector of vector of int. This is where you need to push_back your vector of int, like so:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > myArray(5, std::vector< std::vector<int> >(4));
std::vector<int> testArray;
myArray[0].push_back(testArray);
return 0;
```

With myArray[0][0] you are accessing the vector of int, not vector of vector of int.