# Receiving error while calling push_back() method on Vector class object

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I am receiving the following error while calling push_back() method on the Vector class object:

`error: request for member 'push_back' in 'edges.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(((std::vector<int>::size_type)a))', which is of non-class type 'int'`

I am trying to create a graph using an adjacency list and it isn't working

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

/****************************************/
/// INPUT / OUTPUT
ifstream f("ciclueuler.in");
ofstream g("ciclueuler.out");
/****************************************/
/// GLOBAL DECLARATIONS
int n, m;
const int nmax = 100005;
vector <int> edges;
/****************************************/

inline void readInput()
{
    f >> n >> m;
    for(int  i = 1 ; i <= m ; ++ i)
    {
        int a, b;
        f >> a >> b;
        edges[a].push_back(b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    readInput();
    return 0;
}
```

**Sorry for the bad writing this is my first question!**

Comment: please remove all the code that has nothing to do with your question and create a proper [MCVE]. Then explain what you are trying to achieve and what do you expect `edges[a].push_back(b);` to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 edges[a].push_back(b);
```

`edges[a]` gets the a.th element from the vector. As you use a `vector<int>`, the value you get is an `int`. And you can't call `push_back` on an int, as the type `int` has no member function `push_back`.

`push_back` as the name said, pushes a new value at the end of a vector. So you have to use `edges.push_back(b)`.

If your intention is to insert a new value at a given position, you have to use [std::vector::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `edges[a].push_back(b)` to `edges.push_back(b)`.

And as bolov commented, please explain what are you trying to achieve with `edges[a].push_back(b)`. You ought to call push_back() method directly on the Vector class object.

Checkout this answer, it may help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34608598/9339019

Answer (score 0):

By doing like this you execute the `push_back` method on an `int` and not on a `std::vector`. Try it instead:

```
edges.push_back(b);
```